# Unprotect-PGP not decrypting the file

Tags: powershell, encryption

I am trying to decrypt a .pgp encrypted file. When I run the powershell script, i can see that the same encrypted file is placed at the destination where as we are expecting the decrypted file. Can you please help me why this is not decryting the file. Please note that this decryption worked in SSIS package and i am trying to get this worked in powershell script. Do I need to install any module to get this working.

Please find the code snippet below:

```
Unprotect-PGP -FilePathPrivate $pathlocal -Password $password  -FolderPath "Z:\Informatica\IICS\ProjectFolders\Dev\Government\OSH\Hoshonti" -OutputFolderPath "Z:\Informatica\IICS\ProjectFolders\Dev\Government\OSH"
```

I tried the powershell script and i see the same .pgp file created at destination without decyrption.

I dont see any error as the file is placed in output folder without decrypting.

Comment: Any error messages? If so, please [edit] your post and paste these in there **in full**